# Difference between I would and Would I in following sentences

Tags: sentence-usage

I'm confused between the usage of placement of word **would** in these two sentences:

What **I would** recommend to you is to buy XYZ book from the market.

What **would I** recommend you to is to buy XYZ book from the market.

Please tell when to use Would I and I would?

Please correct if grammatical error(if any in both of sentence)

Comment: Related: ell.stackexchange.com/a/14156/3281. It comes down to whether you'd like to make a statement or a question. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-auxiliary_inversion.

Answer (score 3):

English statements use a subject, maybe an auxiliary verb (or two or three or four auxiliary verbs) and a main verb.
"I would recommend ..." has "I" as its subject, "would" as its modal auxiliary verb and "recommend" as its main verb. The other parts of the sentence don't change this basic grammar.
In English questions, the subject and the (first) auxiliary verb (when there is one) change order.
"Would I recommend ...?" has the auxiliary verb "would" before the subject "I". The two possible questions are:

> "Would I recommend to you to buy something?" (and my own answer to
>   that is, "Yes, I would" (this form is sometimes called a "yes/no question")

and:

> "What would I recommend to you to buy?" (and my own answers to that
>   are "A book", "A particular book" and "XYZ book from the market") (this
>   form is sometimes called a "wh- question" or an "information
>   question").

In both cases, I am asking the question to *myself*, and not to *you*, maybe to check that I've correctly understood your request for a recommendation and maybe to give myself time to think. I don't have to ask *you* what *I* would recommend - I already know, and I'm about to tell you.

Your original sentence is a statement: "What I would recommend to you is to (do this)."

Comment: Is recommend followed by **to**?

Comment: If I say 'What I would recommend to you is ...', then I make it very clear that I am recommending *to you*. But I *can* leave 'to you' out: 'What I would recommend is ...'. If I am talking *to you*, then my recommendation is *to you* unless I specify someone different. I *can* say: 'What I recommend *to your friend* is to buy ABC book, and what I recommend *to you* is to buy XYZ book'. (There are also other ways to say all this, including 'I recommend that you buy ...').  
There is a small group of words which work in the same way, including 'recommend', 'suggest' and 'promise'.

Comment: *What I would recommend you is to buy a but XYZ book.* Is this sentence perfect?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the first statement seems to be correct. This is how it is pronounced -

`What I would recommend you, [pause] is to buy this Book from the Market.`

In this statement, the speaker seems to answer a question which he would have been asked.